# jQuery animate not working on IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-animate

I don't know exactly the reason why it's happening, but in IE the jQuery funcition's behavior isn't working as expected to.
It starts animating and all of a sudden it stops in the middle of the animation.
I still coudn't figure out what is causing the animation to break.

you can see what's happening right here: http://www.globalcomm.com.br/trabalhos
The JS code is in the Header section of the source.

Thanks for all your help.
Cheers.

Comment: Not able to access the link (?)

Comment: What's the problem with the animation? I can scroll the images left and right in IE8 & 7... If it's IE6 help you're after I'm out! :)

Answer (score 0):

The animation seems to work fine in IE6,7 & 8, so not sure where the problem is.